# Storing user input as array in Firebase using Flutter

Tags: java, android, firebase, flutter, dart

In my Flutter project, I have a form in which users can fill their details and upload an image. When the "Submit" button is pressed, a document with the following information is stored in the "Products" collection is Firestore. However, due to the ability of the user to upload more than one image, I want the `imageUrl` to be stored as a String element in the the array of "images" rather than the absolute String value of "images", but I don't know how to do that. For the time being, the code which is responsible for uploading said data is the following:

```
Future<void> addProduct() {
      // Call the user's CollectionReference to add a new product
      return _firebaseAuthServices.productsReference
          .add({
        'name': nameController.text,
        'size': sizeController.text,
        'price': priceController.text,
        'description': descController.text,
        'images': imageUrl,
      })
          .then((value) => print("Product Added"))
          .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add product: $error"));
    }
```

How can I store the value of `imageUrl` as an element of the array of 'images' ?

Comment: Where is the question exactly? Are you using_authservices deliberately?

Comment: I edited the question for it to be more clear and cohesive! The _firebaseAuthServices references to the collection where the data is being stored

Comment: add `imageUrl` as a dynamic list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to add items to lists in firebase

```
Future<void> addProduct() {
      // Call the user's CollectionReference to add a new product
      return _firebaseAuthServices.productsReference
          .add({
        'name': nameController.text,
        'size': sizeController.text,
        'price': priceController.text,
        'description': descController.text,
        'images': FieldValue.arrayUnion([imageUrl]),
      })
          .then((value) => print("Product Added"))
          .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add product: $error"));
    }
```

But this has a flaw, you are using `.add`, so technically your code will add a new document every time you use this, instead of joining the newly added imageUrls only.

You have the option of creating a `List<String>` and also name it `imageUrl`, and when you submit this to firebase, it will be uploaded as a list, using your original code `'images': imageUrl,`.

If the document already exists, and you want to update it later on, use `.update`, like this:

```
 Future<void> upDateProductImages() {
          // Call the user's CollectionReference to add a new product
          return _firebaseAuthServices.productsReference.doc(yourDocID)
              .update({
             'images': FieldValue.arrayUnion([imageUrl]),//here you can add it as a single String url, as in your initial question. Just be sure that the document exists, otherwise it'll throw an error, since you can't update what doesn't exist.
          })
              .then((value) => print("Product Updated"))
              .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add product: $error"));
        }
```

Comment: I can totally see how this is going to work now and I appreciate your help. I had it visualized differently in my mind due to my inexperience with the whole read/write process, but thanks to you it's much clearer ! Thank you so much

Comment: You are most welcome! There's an additional property I didn't mention, it's called `.set`, and you can use `.set({merge:true})` , but get these down first then you can dive into that.If you have any other questions, I'd be happy to help when I can. Happy coding!